# Why is the inverse kinematics not bending straight, but rather slightly off to the side?

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

No matter what I do, it doesn't seem to bend straight. I added a proper 3 chain lengths as well. Here's an image as to how it bends:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. You would need to prevent the IK controller from moving your foot at the same time as the rest of the leg.

First, select both the foot and the foot's IK controller in edit mode, and press "CTRL + P" then "Keep Offset" which prevents it from moving.

Then, to prevent the foot from detaching from the leg, go into pose mode, add a copy transform bone constraint, select your armature as the target, and for the bone select the shin/knee bone. Set the Head/Tail option to 1.

Finally, reorientate your pole angle in the shin/knee IK constraint and you're done.[image]